# Installing Apache Spark on Windows 7 | spark-shell not working

Tags: apache-spark, windows-7, installation

I tried installing Apache Spark on my 64 bit Windwos 7 machine.

I used the guides -

1. [Installing Spark on Windows 10](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Spark_on_Windows10.pdf)
2. [How to run Apache Spark on Windows 7](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html)
3. [Installing Apache Spark on Windows 7 environment](https://edumine.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/how-to-install-apache-spark-on-a-windows-7-environment/)

This is what I did -

1. Install Scala
   Set environment variable SCALA_HOME and add %SCALA_HOME%\bin to Path
   Result: scala command works on command prompt
2. Unpack pre-built Spark
   Set environment variable SPARK_HOME and add %SPARK_HOME%\bin to Path
3. Download winutils.exe
   Place winutils.exe under C:/hadoop/bin
   Set environment variable HADOOP_HOME and add %HADOOP_HOME%\bin to Path

I already have JDK 8 installed.

Now, the problem is, when I run spark-shell from C:/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin, I get this -

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -cp "C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\conf\;C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\*" "-Dscala.usejavacp=true" -Xmx1g org spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell" spark-shell
```

Is it an error? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to install Spark local with Windows 7. Please make sure the below paths is correct and I am sure I will work with you.

- Create JAVA_HOME variable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
- Add the following part to your path: ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
- Create SPARK_HOME variable: C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
- Add the following part to your path: ;%SPARK_HOME%\bin
- The most important part Hadoop path should include bin file before winutils.ee as the following: C:\Hadoop\bin Sure you will locate winutils.exe inside this path.
- Create HADOOP_HOME Variable: C:\Hadoop
- Add the following part to your path: ;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin

Now you can run the cmd and write spark-shell it will work.